# How install or uninstall half-installed mysql-client-5.6 on/from ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: apt, mysql

I probably corrupted my mysql configuration when I tried to install it (again) using the ubuntu package manager (stuck in the middle, because of the required interaction for which there is no screen, (package manager should really give a warning that mysql must be installed via the terminal!)).

Maybe already before, but at least since then, I'm stuck with this error (partly in Dutch):

Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:

mysql-client-5.6

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I get the error when I try to install, as well as when I try to remove the package or any other mysql component.
I found many solutions on the internet that worked for others, but failed in my case. I already did the following (in advised order, which may be different from the list below):

sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo service mysql stop

sudo killall -9 mysql (no process found)

sudo killall -9 mysqld (no process found)

sudo deluser mysql

sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql

sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core-5.5 (fails)

sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql

sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql

sudo apt-get remove mysql-client-5.6 (fails)

sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 (fails)

I could not find a listing of all the files related to mysql, to manually delete the lot.

Any suggestion what else I might try (except reinstalling Ubuntu entirely)?

Comment: Try `apt-get install -f`

Comment: I tried it... but the response is the same as I had so many times already: dpkg: fout bij verwerken van pakket mysql-client-5.6 (--configure):
 pakket mysql-client-5.6 is niet gereed voor configuratie
 kan het niet configureren (huidige status 'half-installed')
Fouten gevonden tijdens verwerken van:
 mysql-client-5.6
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on VM with Ubuntu 14.04. The only thing worked for me is similar to what Richard Uijen has suggested:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove mysql*
sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-client-5.6
```

Basically you need to remove all mysql packages (mysql*), clean and install again

After that I could install php7 mysql client without any issues

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0-mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

Francisco's reply made me go over the

```
sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

error message again (googled with this text and 'half-installed'. 
I then tried (I think: again):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a # (gave same error message) 
sudo dpkg -r mysql-client-5.6 # (error again)
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-client-5.6
```

This time, it installed the package... 
I then removed it. It worked...

After that, when reinstalling mysql-server, it complained about a missing directory, which was solved by making the directory. It appears to be working now.

I'm not sure whether this is a generic solution though...

Thanks.